# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 47: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, encoding

I am using Python 2.7 and MySQLdb 1.2.3. I tried everything I found on stackoverflow and other forums to handle encoding errors my script is throwing.
My script reads data from all tables in a source MySQL DB, writes them in a python `StringIO.StringIO` object, and then loads that data from `StringIO` object to Postgres database (which apparently is in UTF-8 encoding format. I found this by looking into Properties--Definition of database in pgadmin) using psycopg2 library's copy_from command.

I found out that my source MySQL database has some tables in latin1_swedish_ci encoding while others in utf_8 encoding format (Found this from TABLE_COLLATION in information_schema.tables).

I wrote all this code on the top of my Python script based on my research on the internet.

```
db_conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=host,user=user,passwd=passwd,db=db, charset="utf8", init_command='SET NAMES UTF8' ,use_unicode=True) 
db_conn.set_character_set('utf8') 
db_conn_cursor = db_conn.cursor()
db_conn_cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
db_conn_cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
db_conn_cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

I still get the `UnicodeEncodeError` below with this line: `cell = str(cell).replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ").replace("\t", '').replace("\"", "") #Remove unwanted characters from column value`,

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 47: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I wrote the following line of code to clean cells in every table of source MySQL database when writing to StringIO object.

```
cell = str(cell).replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ").replace("\t", '').replace("\"", "") #Remove unwanted characters from column value
```

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`str(cell)` is trying to convert `cell` to ASCII. ASCII only supports characters with ordinals less than 255. What is cell?

If `cell` is a unicode string, just do `cell.encode("utf8")`, and that will return a bytestring encoded as utf 8

...or really iirc. If you pass mysql unicode, then the database will automagically convert it to utf8...

You could also try,

```
cell = unicode(cell).replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ").replace("\t", '').replace("\"", "")
```

or just use a 3rd party library. There is a good one that will fix text for you.

Comment: So, cell is column value for a row in a table (from source MySQL DB where I have enforced UTF-8 read in all ways as you can see above).
cell can hold anything from 1, 50, 100, "Robert", "This is a sentence" etc

Comment: try `print repr(cell)` that will be more helpful (especially right when it crashes)

Comment: I just tried that before and after the str() happens. I got something like this:
For two of the occurrences of cell
Before str(): 2L
After str(): '2'
Before str() : u'Jog'
After str(): 'Jog'
Program doesn't crash for these values of cell btw. I can't write here the text in cell but I can tell you it is a long sentence and has a apostrophe in it '’'

Comment: I need to use str() so that I can use the .replace method to remove unwanted characters from text. Can I transform the str from ascii to utf-8 in python?
In any case, I should try to handle the apostrophe somehow without converting it to str because it fails there

Comment: try this `isinstance(cell.encode("utf8"),str)` ... but unicode has replace as well ... I do not understand why you are calling `str` on your `cell` object

Comment: I realized that the apostrophe character appears as \u2019 in UTF-8, this is currently causing the program to crash.

Comment: When I tried cell.replace("\r", " ") instead of str(cell).replace("\r", " ") --> it throws an error AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continuous help.

So, I figured out that ultimately, I need to write the data in str format because I am writing it to StringIO object (which then copies data to Postgres using copy_from).
However, I had to deal with all those unicode characters like u'u\2018', u'\xc9' etc that couldn't be handled by the str() function.
Hence I imported the unicode python package and used unicode() function to convert all these unicode characters to the closes ASCII characters. Then I did an str() on that. This solved my problems. Thanks.

Comment: you should be able to give unicode directly to StringIO