# 'ascii' encoding error in python

Tags: python, api, unicode, encoding, ascii

I am writing code to get information from the NPR API and I keep running into an encoding error. I tried `.encode('utf-8')` but I can't seem to find where to put it and I keep getting an error.

This is my code:

```
import json
import requests

def pretty(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, sort_keys = True)

def NPR(
    baseurl = 'http://api.npr.org/query?', 
    apiKey = 'MDIzNjY4Mzk5MDE0NjAzMTcwMzNjNGZjOA000',
    id = '1126',
    output = 'json',
    numResults = '50',
    feilds = 'text',
    dateType = 'story',
    cache_fname="cached_data.txt",
    extra_params={}):

    d = {}
    d['id'] = id
    d['feilds'] = feilds
    d['dateType'] = dateType
    d['output'] = output
    d['numResults'] = numResults
    d['apiKey'] = apiKey
    resp = requests.get(baseurl, params = d)
    print resp.url
    print "caching data"
    f = open(cache_fname, 'w')
    f.write(resp.text)
    f.close()
    return resp.text

NPR(cache_fname="NPR_Africa.txt")
```

The error that I get is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 10636: ordinal not in range(128)
```

on the line `f.write(resp.text)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 47: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641027/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u2019-in-position-4)

Answer (score 1):

Open file as text file with utf-8 encoding:

```
f = open(cache_fname, 'wt', encoding='utf-8')
```

But this works just for Python 3.

Python 2:

If resp.text is an unicode string, resp.text.encode('utf-8') should work.

Comment: If the author is explicitly using python 3, this is a better answer than that which is found in the duplicate reference. +1 (That said, this code is python2.x as indicated by the parenthesis-less print statements.)